# Bat File Delete All Directories except the last created

Tags: batch-file

I want to create .bat file which allow me to delete all folder of one directory (C:\Test), except the last created folder (the folder which is the most recent in time). It's easy to me to delete all folder of one directory but try to find the most recent it's not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /ad /tc /o-d "c:\test"') do echo rmdir /s /q "c:\test\%%a"
```

Sort the list of directories in creation time descending, skip the first one, remove the rest.

rmdir commands are echoed to console. If output is correct, remove the `echo` command.

To use it from command line, replace all `%%` with `%`